# Ansible How to read all elements from list

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible ini_file to add lines with the elements reading from a list([dns_a, dns_b, dns_c....]) to my configuration file (test.txt). So the output configuration file (test.txt) should look like this:

```
[dns_name]
DNS.0=dns_a
DNS.1=dns_b
DNS.2=dns_c   
......
```

My code looks like this:

```
var:
  a_list: [dns_a, dns_b dns_c........]

- name: Adding lines to test.txt
  ini_file:
    dest: "/path_to_file/test.txt"
    section: dns_name
    option: DNS.{{item}}
    value: "{{a_list[{{item}}]}}" >>>>>>This line does not work. 
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{a_list|length}} stride=1
```

In the line 'value:', I can reference specific element like {{a_list[0]}}. How do I read all the elements in a_list? My a_list is from Jenkins, so the number of elements in a_list may vary and depend on user input. But the format will be [string1, string2, string3....].

Update: The following updated one is working:

```
var:
  a_list: [dns_a, dns_b dns_c........]

- name: Adding lines to test.txt
  ini_file:
    dest: "/path_to_file/test.txt"
    section: dns_name
    option: DNS.{{item.0}}
    value: "{{item.1}}" 
  with_indexed_items: "{{a_list}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var:
  a_list: [dns_a, dnsB, dns_c........]

- name: Adding lines to test.txt
  ini_file:
    dest: "/path_to_file/test.txt"
    section: dns_name
    option: DNS.{{item}}
    value: "{{a_list[item]}}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, (a_list)| length)|list  }}"
```

output will be like this

```
[dns_name]
DNS.0 = dns_a
DNS.1 = dnsB
DNS.2 = dns_c........
```

Comment: Try this code I have updated it. Think it will work with your version @coding

Comment: @ Grigor, I tried your updated one with 'loop', it did not work. I then tried 'with_indexed_items' you suggested earlier, it worked! I am in 2.3. I searched ansible doc for with_indexed_items. It only showed up in 2.5 and above. Not sure how I got this work in 2.3. Thank you so much for your help